# How can I use SSH to push my repository to GitHub?

Tags: php, git, github, ssh, htdocs

## How can I push my repository to Github using SSH?

### Why

I want to host my repository on GitHub during my PHP 
study.

### What I did

I set remote url of `kaede0902/php` to `htdocs/workspace`, 
and tried to pull. I used sudo.

### Error Message

```
kaede@kaede-ThinkPad-T450:/opt/lampp/htdocs/workspace$ sudo git pull origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '52.69.186.44' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My ssh url is `git@github.com:kaede0902/php.git`.

I am using ssh connection for other repos.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 11):

You have to add your ssh key to both machines.

The error means that you don't have the ssh on your machine.
You can copy the existing one form any of your machines or create a new one.

---

#### Creating and adding ssh key

Source: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

#### Generating ssh key

- Open Git Bash.
- Run `ssh-keygen` and follow the on-screen messages (or simply click <kbd>Enter</kbd> till it over)
- Copy the key file (the content of the public key) located in:

  ```
     ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

#### Add key to Github

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click Settings.
  [image]
- In the user settings sidebar, click SSH and GPG keys.
  [image]
- Click New SSH key or Add SSH key.
  [image]
- Paste your key into the "Key" field.
  [image]
- Click Add SSH key.
  [image]
- **change the repository url to ssh**

  ```
    git remote set-url origin <ssh url>
  ```